# How to validate react select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-select, react-hook-form

I am using [react-select](https://react-select.com/home) for better look on UI, and I have implemented it, Now what I am trying to do is

- I want to validate that input field when user clicks on Done button (form submit)
- I am using [react-hook-form](https://react-hook-form.com) for validation
- They provide `ref={register}` which holds the input field value
- so for normal input field or select I am able to use this like below

```
<label  htmlFor="fname">
    First Name
</label>
<input
    type="text"
    name="fname"
    id="fnameid"
    className="form-control"
    ref={register({
        required: 'First name is required',
    })}
/>

{errors.fname && (
    <div>
        <span className="text-danger">
            {errors.fname.message}
        </span>
    </div>
)}
```

Now the above is working fine but in case of `react-select` I do not know how to go forward

```
<Select
    value={initailSelect}
    onChange={(e) => onChangeAge(e)}
    options={data}
/>
```

So here when I click on submit button it is only taking validation for fname and giving output on console for fname only

I tried doing like below

```
<Select
    value={initailSelect}
    onChange={(e) => onChangeAge(e)}
    options={data}
    ref={register({
        required: 'age is required is required',
    })}
/>
```

[Code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-kepler-lugdf?file=/src/App.js:1762-1775) Here is my code sandbox My working code, Please check

**Edit**

I Tried [This approach](https://codesandbox.io/s/bitter-wave-w1cpi?file=/src/App.js:2084-2802) but it is not taking up `defaultValue` or `Value`, as I want to show one value selected, a nd in some cases I am getting values from server Which I want to show as selected.

Comment: check Controller in react hook form https://react-hook-form.com/get-started#IntegratingwithUIlibraries

Comment: you can use code block for code section to make your question good

Comment: @SreevardhanReddy I already checked and implemented that also, but issue is it is not taking default value.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the link for codesandbox, you can either wrap the component in the Controller or use setValue to manually set values and validate

https://codesandbox.io/s/bitter-wave-w1cpi?file=/src/App.js:2084-2802

https://w1cpi.csb.app/

reference
https://react-hook-form.com/get-started#IntegratingwithUIlibraries

Comment: hey here it is not taking default value or value as I want to show the first one as selected

Comment: I tried with set values there it is not showing the values on submit

Comment: @manishthakur Set value is not working because it is triggered before your field is registered. Try using `setTimeout`